# When i should use adminCreateUser vs signUp in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito

I want to create a pool of users to signup, login, forgot password and change password in my web administrator panel, so far I can not tell the difference between this 2 methods and I dont know which one should I use. I have been reading the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminInitiateAuth-property) with no luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only difference is that using `adminCreateUser` for creating a user will force the created user into `FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD` state until they sign in and change their password however using `signUp` will give the user ability to directly sign in

Comment: Does both implements with amplify?

Comment: @FernandoSantiago Yes