# AWS Cognito sign up from .NET server

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-cognito

I have built an app and a .NET server. I would like to use my server as middleware to bypass sign in/up request to AWS Cognito. I know I need to use `AdminInitiateAuthRequest` for signin. But not sure if it is correct to use `SignUpRequest` for sign up?

Because there is an `InitiateAuthRequest` for frontend to connect cognito directly and a `AdminInitiateAuthRequest` to use in service side.

I only found `SignUpRequest` and `AdminCreateUserRequest`
But `AdminCreateUserRequest` seems will set user status to FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD, which is not ideal

Comment: Can you please explain why you doubt that a method called `SignUp` is the correct method to sign up? Could you please elaborate more on your scenario and what exactly "bypass sign in/up request to AWS Cognito" means? Thank you!

Comment: I have add more details. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When i should use adminCreateUser vs signUp in AWS Cognito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68899356/when-i-should-use-admincreateuser-vs-signup-in-aws-cognito)

Comment: Yea I saw it. But couldn't find a confirmed answer.
Cause the aws docs clearly pointed out for sign in flow that on server shouldser use `AdminInitiateAuthRequest` instead of `SignUpRequest`.
But I cannot find anything for sign up for server side use.

Comment: Please add a link to the docs which say that to the post.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-server-side-authentication-flow

Comment: Where is "instead of `SignUpRequest`" coming from?

Comment: Ah sorry my bad I meant to say instead of `InitiateAuthRequest`.
My understand is `InitiateAuthRequest` and `SignUpRequest` are for frontend apps.

`AdminInitiateAuthRequest` is for server side sign in, but just want to know if `SignUpRequest` is also for server side sign up